# Can I add multiple Envoy filter of the same type in the filter chain?

Tags: envoyproxy

For example I want to limit http bandwith of request & response to different kbps. but envoy `envoy.filters.http.bandwidth_limit` only supports one configuration. So can I add the filter twice in the filter chain with different configurations?